# A Simpler Analogy for Zero-Knowledge Proof in Cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

I just read the Wikipedia article about zero-knowledge proof/protocol at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof. I understood the story of Peggy and Victor but I have a question. Could not Peggy just enter the cave from Path A and exit the cave at Path B, the whole process being watched by Victor, who is standing at the bifurcation of Path A and B? I did not see any problem of this plan of violating the rule of completeness, soundness, and zero-knowledge. In addition, it is definitive: Peggy can just prove he knows the magic word with one try. So what is wrong with that plan?

Comment: If the whole process is watched by Victor it's not zero-knowledge because he will see how she opens the door, when the only thing he was supposed to learn was whether Peggy can open the door (not how she does it).